# Zebra SDK Scanner events

Tags: sdk, barcode-scanner

Some examples of how to use the scanning properties?, I already followed the instructions on how to use the API, but the methods to capture a label and how to decode it do not know how to use them, some example of how to do it would be very helpful

I already analyzed the sample app and in the "Decoded Barcode" field I do not understand how they activate the event of scanning the tag and decoding it im using c# .NET

Comment: Which Zebra scanner are you using?

Comment: Im using the Symbol DS3578

Comment: The latest SDK is available from https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/scanner-sdk-for-windows.html, I notice only the most recent version is published and does not claim support for the DS3578 but if you install that SDK the source code for the sample app gets installed locally on your machine - hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks!
I already have the SDK installed and i already used and make some code but i have some trouble getting started, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can activate the scanning event through the `barcodeEvent`.

From the [SDK](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/software/sdk-windows_devguide_en.pdf#page=46):

> ### BarcodeEvent:
>
> Triggered when a scanner captures bar codes. To receive BarcodeEvents, an application needs to execute the REGISTER_FOR_EVENTS method with the SUBSCRIBE_BARCODE event type.